# OpenSceneGraph integration into Qt Quick

Tags: android, qt, opengl-es, qtquick2, openscenegraph

I want to integrate OSG scene into my Qt Quick application.

It seems that the proper way to do it is to use `QQuickFramebufferObject` class and call `osgViewer::Viewer::frame()` inside `QQuickFramebufferObject::Renderer::render()`. I've tried to use https://bitbucket.org/leon_manukyan/qtquick2osgitem/overview.

However, it seems this approach doesn't work correctly in all cases. For example, in Android platform this code renders only the first frame.

I think the problem is that `QQuickFramebufferObject` uses the same OpenGL context both for Qt Quick Scene Graph and code called within `QQuickFramebufferObject::Renderer::render()`.

So I'm wondering, is it possible to integrate OpenSceneGraph into Qt Quick using `QQuickFramebufferObject` correctly or it is better to use implementation that uses `QQuickItem` and separate OpenGL context such as https://github.com/podsvirov/osgqtquick?

Comment: Will you be satisfied with QImage painted on OpenGL surface of QQuickItem?

Comment: The `QQuickItem` and `QQuickFramebufferObject` are pretty straightforward wrappers around OpenGL. They can't just "not work". Maybe try to use `QSGNode::markDirty()` in `updatePaintNode()` and check that `render()` and `updatePaintNode()` are called all the time.

Comment: @AlexanderVX, If it will be fast enough and will work both for desktop and mobile platforms, yes.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to integrate OpenSceneGraph into Qt Quick using
>   QQuickFramebufferObject correctly or it is better to use
>   implementation that uses QQuickItem and separate OpenGL context?

The easiest way would be using [QQuickPaintedItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickpainteditem.htm) which is derived from QQuickItem. While it is by default offering raster-image type of drawing you can switch its render target to OpenGL [FramebufferObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickpainteditem.html#RenderTarget-enum):

> QPainter paints into a QOpenGLFramebufferObject using the GL paint
>   engine. Painting can be faster as no texture upload is required, but
>   anti-aliasing quality is not as good as if using an image. This render
>   target allows faster rendering in some cases, but you should avoid
>   using it if the item is resized often.

```
MyQQuickItem::MyQQuickItem(QQuickItem* parent) : QQuickPaintedItem(parent)
{
    // unless we set the below the render target would be slow rastering
    // but we can definitely use the GL paint engine just by doing this:
    this->setRenderTarget(QQuickPaintedItem::FramebufferObject);
}
```

How do we render with this OpenGL target then? The answer can be still good old QPainter filled with the image called on update/paint:

```
void MyQQuickItem::presentImage(const QImage& img)
{
    m_image = img;
    update();
}

// must implement
// virtual void QQuickPaintedItem::paint(QPainter *painter) = 0
void MyQQuickItem::paint(QPainter* painter)
{
    // or we can precalculate the required output rect
    painter->drawImage(this->boundingRect(), m_image);
}
```

While [QOpenGLFramebufferObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglframebufferobject.html) used behind the scenes here is not [QQuickFramebufferObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickframebufferobject.html) the semantics of it is pretty much what the question is about and we've confirmed with the question author that we can use QImage as a source to render in OpenGL.

P.S. I successfully use this technique since Qt 5.7 on PC desktop and singleboard touchscreen Linux device. Just a bit unsure of Android.

Comment: Yes, it look nice, bot how should I render into QImage my OpenSceneGraph scene?

Comment: By replacing QQuickItem with its child class QQuickPaintedItem and then implementing the above. No OpenSceneGraph involved anymore. I do streaming video through that as long as Qt Multimedia VideoOutput is ****.

Comment: ok, it seems that I completely didn't understand you. I need to render OpenSceneGraph model in my Qt Quick application. But in solution above I didn't see any point where I can call `osgViewer::frame()` method to render scene.