# How to optimize QPainter::drawPolyline()

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, paint, qpainter

I have a `QQuickPaintedItem`'s children class that may draw a large polylines (>100k points). The following method is used in `QQuickPaintedItem::paint()`:

```
// the method being called in QQuickPaintedItem::paint()
void Plotter::drawCurves(QPainter *painter) 
{
    // ...

    QLinkedList<QPointF> data = iterator.value();

    QPolygonF polyline(data.count());
    QPointF point;
    int i = 0;

    foreach (point, data)
        polyline[i++] = transformToCoord(point);

    QTime timer;
    timer.start();
    painter->drawPolyline(polyline);
    qDebug() << timer.elapsed();
}

void Plotter::paint(QPainter *painter)
{
    // ...
    drawCurves(painter);
    // ...
}
```

Painting of 100k points with `QPainter::drawPolyline()` takes about 120-170 milliseconds. Method `QQuickPaintedItem::update()` calls very often so drawing a polyline reduces program perfomance a lot.

Is there a way to speed up `QPainter::drawPolyline()`?

Comment: Cannot answer as question asked with just "how to optimize this one function" but overall QQuickPaintedItem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46187024/openscenegraph-integration-into-qt-quick/46201000#46201000

Comment: @AlexanderVX It works! Thanks. You can post the answer.

Comment: Glad that works for you.